# How to do \widthof with a symbol

Tags: width

I have the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
c_s &\equiv b_s^2\\
&\equiv (c_{s-1}^{(2^{k_{s-1}-k_s-1})})^2 \\
&\equiv c_{s-1}^{(2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})} \\
&\equiv c_{s-2}^{(2^{k_{s-2}-k_{s-1}} \cdot 2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})}\\
&\mathrel{\makebox[\widthof{=}]{\vdots}}\\
&\equiv c_0^{(2^{k_{0}-k_{1}} \cdot \cdots \cdot 2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})} \pmod p
\end{align*}
```

On the third last line, I want to change the argument to `\widthof` to be `\equiv`, but doing this gives me compile error. What do I need to do to achieve the desired result?

Comment: as it happens, the width of `equiv` is exactly the same as that of `=`.  (this should be true in *all* fonts designed for use with math.)  however, the general question is a reasonable one, and the `mathtools` answer is a good one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use

```
\widthof{$\equiv$}
```

but there's a slicker way with `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
c_s &\equiv b_s^2\\
&\equiv (c_{s-1}^{(2^{k_{s-1}-k_s-1})})^2 \\
&\equiv c_{s-1}^{(2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})} \\
&\equiv c_{s-2}^{(2^{k_{s-2}-k_{s-1}} \cdot 2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})}\\
&\vdotswithin{\equiv}\\
&\equiv c_0^{(2^{k_{0}-k_{1}} \cdot \cdots \cdot 2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})} \pmod{p}  
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The space might seem too big, so `\mathtools` also provides `\shortvdotswithin`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{shortvdotsadjustabove=3pt} % I don't like the default

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
c_s &\equiv b_s^2\\
&\equiv (c_{s-1}^{(2^{k_{s-1}-k_s-1})})^2 \\
&\equiv c_{s-1}^{(2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})} \\
&\equiv c_{s-2}^{(2^{k_{s-2}-k_{s-1}} \cdot 2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})}\\
&\shortvdotswithin{\equiv}
&\equiv c_0^{(2^{k_{0}-k_{1}} \cdot \cdots \cdot 2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})} \pmod{p}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that there is no `\\` after `\shortvdotswithin{\equiv}`.

Be careful that it's `\pmod{p}` and not `\pmod p`. The latter seems to work, but try `\pmod 11` and you'll see.

Answer (score 7):

The argument of `\widthof` (package `calc`) is set in text mode. Mathematical symbols need math mode:

```
\widthof{$\equiv$}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
c_s &\equiv b_s^2\\
&\equiv (c_{s-1}^{(2^{k_{s-1}-k_s-1})})^2 \\
&\equiv c_{s-1}^{(2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})} \\
&\equiv c_{s-2}^{(2^{k_{s-2}-k_{s-1}} \cdot 2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})}\\
&\mathrel{\makebox[\widthof{$\equiv$}]{\vdots}}\\
&\equiv c_0^{(2^{k_{0}-k_{1}} \cdot \cdots \cdot 2^{k_{s-1}-k_s})} \pmod p
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: shouldn't it be with `\m@th` ?

Comment: hmm no, examining `\mathsurround` I see that `align` sets `\mathsurround` to `0pt` immediately after `&`. Still it is strange,  try `\mathssurround200pt \begin{align}\the\mathssurround&\the\mathsurround,\the\mathsurround\end{align}`. The last one prints `0pt`! And if I put a `\relax` after `&`, then we get `0pt, 0pt` after it.

Comment: ah, I see that it is a feature of amsmath that `\m@th` is issued for each cell. Coming from an `\halign` template the `\m@th` at each cell becomes effective only after TeX's usual scan at start of cell has been stopped by some non-expandable token. So `\relax\the\mathssurround` is needed to reveal the setting. For all purposes `\mathsurround` is `0pt` inside (each cell of an) `align`. I was not aware of that.

Comment: @jfbu A generic macro would have to consider `\m@th`/`\mathsurround` and the math style (`\mathpalette`/`\mathchoice`). But I do not think, that it is necessary in ad hoc code to take precautions for all the quite unlikely cases.